# The SVG animation has an attribute dur, but is there a way to set the speed of the animation instead?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

This code for SVG animation produces a different speed for each rectangle. I need SIMILAR speeds (DIFFERENT duration). Is there an attribute that i can't find for this, or a simple solution.

---

```
<animate attributeName="x" attributeType="XML" begin="0s" dur="10s" from="0" to="500" fill="freeze"/>
```

```
<animate attributeName="x" attributeType="XML" begin="0s" dur="10s" from="0" to="800" fill="freeze"/>
```

Comment: You could use maths. Or, you could simply say `dur="5s" from="0" to="500"` and `dur="8s" from="0" to="800"`

Comment: Basically, `speed = distance/time` so `time = distance/speed`

Comment: @Shmiddty would prefer if their was a an attribute to define it. There is a "pace" attribute which I'm reading into: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html However, the api is a bit wordy, and I get don't think it does what I want.

Comment: I think you'll find that it really isn't that complicated.

Comment: @Shmiddty  yeah, i guess, I just like to know the if its possible. Plus, I mite not always know what the distance will be... attribute to="100" from="[where ever i am at the moment]" cant use getAttribute() because if i used animate to get to the current position... for some reason it doesn't register.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to set up a speed animation:

```
<animate attributeName="x" attributeType="XML" begin="0s" dur="10s" from="0" to="800" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0 1 0" />
```

**calcMode="spline"** and **keySplines="0 0 1 0"** is responsible for the speed

It is rather inconvenient to set right speed in "hand-mode". So this tool in help: http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/keysplines.svg

Answer (score 0):

No. SVG Animation is time based. calcmode="paced" which is what you might be referring to is simply the default animation mode (vs. discrete where animation jumps from start to finish). If you want a JavaScript style "setInterval()" animation, you have to use JavaScript.